# "stringValues" is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jslint

I'm new to JS and I am trying to call a function inside another function. When I try it I am getting the lint error.
- stringValues inserts comma in between numbers to display correct formats, for 1000 it displays as 1,000 and for 10000 it displays as 10,000

```
 return Number(unitsOfNumbers.join('')).stringValues();
```

- providing my code and error below.

ERROR:

```
"stringValues" is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

CODE:

```
  import {differentCountriesCurrency} from 'sports-input-utils/lib/formatting';

    Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
        value: true
    });
    exports.appleBrowser = appleBrowser;
    exports.appleBrowserWithDecimals = appleBrowserWithDecimals;


    function stringValues(x, sep, grp) {
        var sx = (''+x).split('.'), s = '', i, j;
        sep || (sep = ','); // default seperator
        grp || grp === 0 || (grp = 3); // default grouping
        i = sx[0].length;
        while (i > grp) {
            j = i - grp;
            s = sep + sx[0].slice(j, i) + s;
            i = j;
        }
        s = sx[0].slice(0, i) + s;
        sx[0] = s;
        return sx.join('.');
    }

    function appleBrowser(value, parm) {
        var unitsOfNumbers;
        if (!value) {
            return value;
        }

        // extract unitsOfNumbers. if no unitsOfNumbers, fill in a zero.
        unitsOfNumbers = value.match(/\d/g) || ['0'];
        return Number(unitsOfNumbers.join('')).stringValues();
    }

    function appleBrowserWithDecimals(value, parm) {
        var unitsOfNumbers;
        if (!value) {
            return value;
        }

        // extract unitsOfNumbers. if no unitsOfNumbers, fill in a zero.
        unitsOfNumbers = value.match(/\d/g) || ['0'];

        // zero-pad a one-digit input
        if (unitsOfNumbers.length === 1) {
            unitsOfNumbers.unshift('0');
        }

        // add a decimal point
        unitsOfNumbers.splice(unitsOfNumbers.length - 2, 0, '.');

        return Number(unitsOfNumbers.join('')).stringValues();
    }
    //# sourceMappingURL=formatting.js.map

    exports.limitMaximumLength = limitMaximumLength;
    function limitMaximumLength(value, parm) {
        if (value.length < parm) {
            return value;
        } else {
            return value.substring(0, parm);
        }
    }

    exports.differentCountriesCurrencyWithMaxLen = differentCountriesCurrencyWithMaxLen;
    function differentCountriesCurrencyWithMaxLen (value) {
        var isSafari;
        return differentCountriesCurrency(limitMaximumLength(value, 7));

        isSafari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;
        if (isSafari) {
            return appleBrowser(limitMaximumLength(value, 7));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `stringValues()` is not a member of Number, but a normal function. You never use the stringValues you define

Comment: @JosephYoung thanks for your reply...can you update in my code...its confusing :(

Comment: What do you want stringValues to do? What does it even do?

Comment: It inserts comma in between numbers to display correct formats

Comment: @JosephYoung stringValues inserts comma in between numbers to display correct formats, for 1000 it displays as 1,000 and for 10000 it displays as 10,000

Answer (score 1):

Not worrying about other linting errors or checking anything about the logic (haven't checked if it does what you want or not), I can remove the `no-unused-vars` error like this:

```
import {differentCountriesCurrency} from 'sports-input-utils/lib/formatting';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
    value: true
});

function stringValues(x, sep, grp) {
    var sx = (''+x).split('.'), s = '', i, j;
    sep || (sep = ','); // default seperator
    grp || grp === 0 || (grp = 3); // default grouping
    i = sx[0].length;
    while (i > grp) {
        j = i - grp;
        s = sep + sx[0].slice(j, i) + s;
        i = j;
    }
    s = sx[0].slice(0, i) + s;
    sx[0] = s;
    return sx.join('.');
};

exports.appleBrowser = function (value, parm) {
    var unitsOfNumbers;
    if (!value) {
        return value;
    }

    // extract unitsOfNumbers. if no unitsOfNumbers, fill in a zero.
    unitsOfNumbers = value.match(/\d/g) || ['0'];
    return stringValues(Number(unitsOfNumbers.join('')));
};

exports.appleBrowserWithDecimals = function (value, parm) {
    var unitsOfNumbers;
    if (!value) {
        return value;
    }

    // extract unitsOfNumbers. if no unitsOfNumbers, fill in a zero.
    unitsOfNumbers = value.match(/\d/g) || ['0'];

    // zero-pad a one-digit input
    if (unitsOfNumbers.length === 1) {
        unitsOfNumbers.unshift('0');
    }

    // add a decimal point
    unitsOfNumbers.splice(unitsOfNumbers.length - 2, 0, '.');

    return stringValues(Number(unitsOfNumbers.join('')));
};

exports.limitMaximumLength = function (value, parm) {
    if (value.length < parm) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return value.substring(0, parm);
    }
};

exports.differentCountriesCurrencyWithMaxLen = function (value) {
    var isSafari;
    return differentCountriesCurrency(limitMaximumLength(value, 7)); 
    // ^^^ There's no way this ^^^ is what you want. 
    // The rest of the function is always ignored. You've already returned.

    isSafari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;
    if (isSafari) {
        return appleBrowser(limitMaximumLength(value, 7));
    }
};
```

To remove the error, I did exactly what @JosephYoung says. You haven't added `stringValues` to whatever Number returns. You declared it globally.

So don't do this:

```
return Number(unitsOfNumbers.join('')).stringValues();
```

That pretends there's another `stringValues` as a function-property on `Number`'s return value. Your function `stringValues` exists at global scope, and is never called.

To call what you declared, you do this:

```
return stringValues(Number(unitsOfNumbers.join('')));
```

---

One important readability issue to notice: Instead of the lines you have like this...

```
exports.limitMaximumLength = limitMaximumLength;
function limitMaximumLength(value, parm) {
```

... go ahead and put the assignment on a single line like this...

```
exports.limitMaximumLength = function (value, parm) {
```

Makes it easier to tell what you're exporting and what's a "private" utility function.